# How to whitelist IP address mod_security CentOS 6

Tags: mod-security, centos

Is it possible to white list an IP address in mod_security?

I found white ist whole domain name in mod_security. But I want to white list only the administrator IP.

OS: CentOS 6
Server: Apache httpd 2.15
Mod Security: Version 2.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the way.

```
vim /etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_10_whitelist.conf
```

And add this line:

```
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "^192\.168\.50\.1$" phase:1,log,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=Off,id:999945
```

Answer (score 1):

I use modsec version 3 and in my case there wasn't a modsec configuration file in the location `/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_10_whitelist.conf` but there was one in:

```
/etc/modsecurity/crs/REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION-RULES-BEFORE-CRS.conf
```

in this file the following example is given:

```
# ModSec Rule Exclusion: Disable Rule Engine for known ASV IP
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch 192.168.1.100" \
    "phase:1,id:1000,pass,nolog,ctl:ruleEngine=Off"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are under a load Balancer use:

```
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:X-Forwarded-For "@Contains 37.161.74.122" phase:1,nolog,allow,pass,ctl:ruleEngine=off,id:1
```